# How can we gain support of the Raspberry Pi foundation?

Tags: discussion, promotion

The Raspberry Pi foundation has made it relatively clear that they want their forums to provide the majority of support for Raspberry Pi Q&A and discussion.  A key player in promotion for this site is the foundation themselves.  While it isn't necessary to gain their endorsement, it would definitely help.  Are there any **specific contacts or players** we should reach out to or any strategies we could use to gain their support.

Comment: Any links to where have they "made it relatively clear"?

Comment: They replied to my tweet earlier.. https://twitter.com/Raspberry_Pi/status/212633550313365505. I wouldn't read too much into that, but I do think we should tread carefully. I don't believe it's wise to start 'promoting' SE all over the forums. It will likely antagonize the existing users and make them less inclined to check SE out.

Comment: @MattJ I had a post I could link to, but it got deleted.

Comment: @popey We're not here to compete with the forums. That tweet seemed somewhat snoody

Comment: @KyleMacey which tweet and what does "snoody" mean? I know we're not competing. I have some experience of this exact same scenario with Askubuntu and Ubuntu forums, so I'm not surprised by the reticence of the foundation.

Comment: @popey they're Tweet. I don't know, maybe snarky would have been a better word?

Comment: I see. I dunno, I wouldn't think that was intentional. They probably get a lot of attention and many people want to ride off the back of the popularity. I guess they want to draw the line somewhere so they don't spread themselves too thin, or duplicate effort. Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I still can't find where, but they did say they were wary of sites trying to make a "quick buck."

Comment: Nice thing about SE... Even if the "official" answers are locked up in a forum, citing them here allows them to be expanded, updated, improved, and most of all *found*. Prove your worth by being awesome - if they still don't want a part of that, you'll still be awesome.

Comment: @Shog9 For sure.  It's definitely not about validation: the beauty of the SE network is it's basically a meritocracy.  If a site can be successful, it will be.  It would just make building a great community full of experts easier if we got their support.

Answer (score 4):

There is a thread here on the RaspPi forum mentioning this SE site:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=6223

In the meantime I'd suggest the best thing we can do to support the RaspPi foundation and attract their attention is to add as much value to this SE site as we can. Not stepping on the toes of the forum is a good way to do this. That way both can happily co-exist and support the RaspPi community by generating a new resource rather than spreading the same functionality across multiple locations.

Also see: [Stack Exchange site vs. forum](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/stack-exchange-site-vs-forum)