# Showcase your serving of Pi?

Tags: discussion, scope

I appreciate that this is a Q&A-type site, which therefore encourages "I have a problem..." type questions.

I'm pretty sure that success stories, (or even better, initially unsuccessful, but resolved case studies) could promote the Pi and this forum.

However, the SE concept seems to preclude this.

Currently, we do not have a Blog for RasPi.SE - so is it appropriate to have have "Showcase" threads, of the form *This is what I've used my Pi for, and this is how I did it (and these are the problems I overcame)*

Is this OK?  Perhaps with a `Showcase` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure that success stories, (or even better, initially unsuccessful, but resolved case studies) could promote the Pi and this forum.

Stack Exchange sites aren't really intended to be used as forums.  Initially unsuccessful, but resolved case studies can be useful *when structured in the Stack Exchange Question & Answer format.*  For instance, someone who solved their own complicated problem could answer their own question.

Threads of the form *This is what I've used my Pi for* are ultimately not constructive for a Stack Exchange site.  In fact, this kind of thing is exactly what the [official Raspberry Pi forums are for](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18/20).

Ultimately, you sort of answer your own question here:

> However, the SE concept seems to preclude this.

A great rule of thumb for Stack Exchange is that if something doesn't fit the format, it belongs elsewhere.

Comment: Not anymore - http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/

Comment: This answer still applies--the Q&A portion is not appropriate for the "showcase" format, though the blog **may** be if that ends up being within its scope.

Comment: I think I'll start a blog proposal then :-)

Comment: Great idea!  Thanks for posting it!

Comment: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/346/blog-for-the-raspberrypi is my post.

Answer (score 2):

If you go through some of my questions, you'll see that I've answered a few of them. Self-answered questions can be used to showcase what you have done, but they should still be showcasing how you solved a problem rather than just what you have done, where Instructables may be more appropriate.