# Should I ask a question on what people do with their Raspberry Pi?

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of projects you can do with a Raspberry Pi.  Would it be acceptable to ask a question to poll people on what projects they use their Raspberry Pi with?

It is kind of meant to be a broad question, with lots of responses.  The projects that people like most get upvoted to the top, making it easier for people looking at project ideas to find something to do.

If the answer is yes, what should some criteria/requirements be for answers to the question?

Comment: The reason I ask this is because it seems every site has their own little "forum" post that they have done (or even do [on a regular basis](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/106036?hq=1)) Some good examples of this are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (this one still being not locked or closed due to the decision by the community on meta questions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, **no**.

Longer answer, Stack Exchange [is not a forum](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18/20).  There are places for project discussion to occur, and while projects are really exciting questions like this generally make Stack Exchange sites *less* useful as a resource.

There are a few times when projects might be relevant:

- As an answer to a question on implementation (Q: How do I create a media server A: Here's a detailed explanation of how I did it)
- As a self-answered question based on a problem you encountered while working on a project, and what you were doing with your Raspberry Pi is relevant

Otherwise, you can jump into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery) to discuss whatever you'd like.  We've had a couple people share projects and we've [highlighted them in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10711144#10711144).

Currently we are exploring [using a blog](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/403/20) for this.  Go chime in on that question if you'd like to help with that!

Comment: Good answer:  Also, such a question would be no different to asking on other SE sites "What do you do with your PC?".

Comment: @Chenmunka I disagree completely.  While the Raspberry Pi has the capabilities of a PC, it also has a lot more distinct features from a PC.

Comment: @syb0rg I agree, the RPi and PC are very different animals.  The nature of development projects on the two devices is different but my point is that the concept is the same.  A project question is more of a discussion than is normally accepted here.  I believe jandjorgensen is spot on in saying that such discussions are best served elsewhere.

Comment: Like maybe...[a blog](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/403/do-we-want-a-community-blog-what-will-it-be-about-and-who-will-contribute?cb=1)?

Comment: @jandjorgensen The problem with a blog is that it takes a lot of effort and time to write a post.  However, and answer to a question like the one I'm proposing doesn't take as much time.  I like the idea though.

Comment: @syb0rg So, ideally we'll have regular contributors who *want* to write for the blog.  People who want to share projects won't necessarily have to write about them (though maybe they'll want to).  Also, a project post is only useful to future visitors (within the goals of SE) if a lot of time and effort goes into it. Even if you could post projects as questions, ones that didn't have the effort of a blog post might end up removed.