# Do we want a community blog, what will it be about, and who will contribute?

Tags: discussion, blog

The proposition of a blog has been raised before, but I'd like to start planning it if the community would like to work on it. It seems like there is [some demand for, at the very least, a project blog](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/401/20), so I'd like to leave it up to the community to determine whether this is feasible.

Here's what we need for this to happen:

## Scope

Obviously, we need to highlight projects because people in the community have asked for a place to do this.  Is there anything else we'd like the blog to include?

## Contributors

We need some people committed to writing and some people *committed to editing*.  The people in charge will ideally be regular users from the community instead of moderators (though obviously you'll have moderator support where possible).  If you're interested, we need to know *how often you're willing to post* and *if you're willing to put time into research*.

## Schedule

We also have to decide how often we'll post.  We probably need to stick to a specific schedule, which may be hard based on frequency of projects.  If there is a post once a month will it be a round up of projects or highlight one specifically and clearly?  If we post every two weeks?

## Planning

How will we plan blog posts?  First, we will start a project specific chat room (which we may do now anyway).  We'll schedule events so contributors and people working on projects can talk and figure things out.

If you have any feedback or suggestions, leave an answer to this.  If you're interested in this sort of thing happening in general, upvote the question and upvote suggestions and feedback you like.

Comment: Why limit the blog to only projects? What about community news and events (both the raspberrypi.stackexchange community and the wider pi community)? 

It may also be helpful to discuss what other outlets there are for this type of information, and what and how we can do things better or differently.

Comment: Edited to reflect a more general blog possibility.

Comment: Beyond the S.E. blog, I wasn't aware this was an official possibility.  Do you have any more information about that?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/

Comment: For future reference: [announcement of the current blog](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/755/we-started-a-blog)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Contributors

Edit this and put in your name below (and link to your profile) if you're interested in either role (or both).

### Writers

Putting your name here should be a commitment to write *regularly* for the blog (a post every 1-2 months).

- [goldilocks](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5538/goldilocks) - I have a C/C++ library for a simple adafruit device I'd like to make public, and some applications based on that.
- [jandjorgensen](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/20/jandjorgensen) - Interested in highlighting community members' projects
- [jivings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334274/jivings) - Community projects, Raspberry Pi news, Raspberry Jams, personal projects.
- [syb0rg](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/8631/syb0rg) - Interviews with the users of this site, personal projects.
- [Patrick Cook](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/33979/patrick-cook) - Personal projects and Raspberry Pi News.

  ### Editors

  - [jandjorgensen](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/20/jandjorgensen)
  - [goldilocks](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5538/goldilocks)
  - [syb0rg](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/8631/syb0rg)
  - [RPiAwesomeness](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/9475/rpi-awesomeness)

Comment: Will users earn reputation from this?

Answer (score 6):

I think we should decide on some basic criteria so if someone says, "I want to contribute to the blog," we'll have those as guidelines to point to.

**For example:** *The project should be public, and we should not be a primary distribution point or main reference.*  In other words, it should be a project that is already hosted online somewhere, even if it is just github or sourceforge.   If it's proprietary, that's fine, but it should still have a home page somewhere else.  This means:

- The blogs can be restricted to a reasonably concise description/discussion, including external links to downloads, documentation, etc.
- 'Programming diary' style things would not be allowed ("I'm working on whatever, and it's not really done yet, but here's how it's been going...") etc.

---

**Another idea:** We could create some kind of *optional* template.  People could use this to structure their blog, but would not be required to use it, and could interpret it as they wish.

Comment: "The project should be public, and we should not be a primary distribution point or main reference." Agreed.  I think this is a great guideline.  Also, second that "programming diary" shouldn't be allowed.  I'd like to keep along with the SE philosophy of being as useful to future visitors as possible.